# Python says it is running with elevated access but it is still returning an error?

Tags: python, subprocess

I was recently trying to create a script that will keep track of outgoing TCP connections but I ran into an error when trying to run TCPView.exe. The script below should grant elevated access but it still returns this: `OSError: [WinError 740]` The requested operation requires elevation. I think it's because it's granting permission for `python` to have elevated access but not `TCPView`. Still not sure how to solve this.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import win32com.shell.shell as shell



def get_tcp_conns():
    process = Popen([r"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\TCPView\Tcpview.exe"], stdout=PIPE)
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
        print(line)  # Do whatever here


ASADMIN = 'asadmin'

if sys.argv[-1] != ASADMIN:
    script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
    params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [ASADMIN])
    shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile=sys.executable, lpParameters=params)
    get_tcp_conns()

    
with open("somefilename.txt", "w") as out:
    print(out, "i am root")
    get_tcp_conns()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of this:**

```
process = Popen([r"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\TCPView\Tcpview.exe"], stdout=PIPE)
```

**Try this:**

```
process = Popen([r"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\TCPView\Tcpview.exe"], stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
```

Namely, set the `shell` parameter to `True`.